# Elasticsearch data schema for nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm building an Elasticsearch index that spans across multiple types of associated objects.

I've tried several approaches, but I can't seem to find the right balance between performance, scalability, and matching product requirements.

Here's the stripped down data model:

```
user
* id
* email
* created_at
...

has many:

  associated_1
  * type
  * created_at
  ...


  associated_2
  * type
  * created_at
  ...
```

The goal is to run a query that will:

- return users,
- filtered by `email`,
- filtered by `associated_1` `type`,
- sorted by `associated_2` `created_at`.

I've tried several approaches.

1. Nested documents. This won't really work since `user` has a certain level of churn (updates), some nested objects as well. That would mean a lot of reindexing of quite complex objects.
2. Parent / child. This works, but also makes data retention problematic, see below.
3. Separate indexes. By far the best way to store data - multiple indexes, an index per object. For this approach I haven't really found a way to run the query with multi-level filtering and sorting, except for shooting multiple queries at ES and then somehow merging and sorting results. But this doesn't seem to be scalable.

To add another level of complexity - I also need to retire data after a certain period of time. Main `user` object should sit in the index all the time, while associated objects have a TTL (I'm doing TTL with daily indexes).

My preferred solution would be `3`, but I don't know how to query that.
Alternative solution would be `2`, but that adds a lot of data duplication, since I would need to copy `user` object to every daily index to maintain parent / child association.

I'm also open to another search / analytics engines, besides Elasticsearch.

Any help / comments / recommendations are appreciated!

Comment: If that helps, data duplication (aka denormalization) is not at all an issue for Elasticsearch. The ultimate end goal being to have very fast reads, you need to take an approach that will get you the data you need without having to do too many queries (ideally a single one) and that's usually achieved by indexing documents that are as self-contained as it gets.

Comment: Thanks @Val, that is helpful, and indeed - this is my preferred solution at this point. The only problem with that approach would be the amount of duplicated data, which can easily reach dozens of GBs, and I'm trying to avoid that. But if there's no other solution that's what I'll have to do.

Comment: You've made a good job at describing the situation but it's still not enough details to have a good grasp at your problem domain. So it's hard to tell whether this is the right way (my gut feeling after having designed dozens of projects with vaguely similar descriptions) or if there are other ways.

Comment: Some more food for thoughts: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4604579+denormalization+nested